# Image is not displaying (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: c#, json, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have shown the data on screen except image now i also want to see image as i can see all the data like id name etc, below are the codes:
What changes do i need to make and where?

Page 1 XAML C sharp code: (Changes on this page?)

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        public UserResponse result;
        public String test;
        public MyUser user;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //     Task.Run(async () => await GetinfoAsync());  
            _ = GetinfoAsync();
        }
        public async Task GetinfoAsync()
        {
            var responseString = await client.GetStringAsync("https://reqres.in/api/users/2");

            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserResponse>(responseString); 

            if (result != null)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    test = dis.Text = "Id:- " + result.Data.id + "\nEmail:- " + result.Data.email + "\nFirst Name:- " + result.Data.first_name + "\nLast Name:- " + result.Data.last_name + "\nImage:- " + result.Data.avatar; dis.Text = test;
                });
            }
        }

        private async void click_me(Object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            await this.Navigation.PushAsync(new Data(result));
        }
```

Page 2 XAML C sharp Code: (Changes on this page?)

```
public partial class Data : ContentPage
    {

        private MyUser _obj;
        public MyUser obj
        {
            get { return _obj; }
            set
            {
                _obj = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public String show;

        public Data(UserResponse result)
        {
            //show = test;
            InitializeComponent();
            obj = result.Data;
            // displaylabel.Text = test;

        }
```

Page 2 XAML code for design:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="demo.Data" x:Name="MyPage" >
    <ContentPage.Content >

        <StackLayout Padding="20">
            <Label Text="Id" TextColor="Red" />
            <Editor BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=MyPage}" Text="{Binding obj.id}"   IsReadOnly="True" />
            <Label Text="First Name" TextColor="Red"/>
            <Editor BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=MyPage}" Text="{Binding obj.first_name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <Label Text="Last Name" TextColor="Red"/>
            <Editor BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=MyPage}" Text="{Binding obj.last_name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <Label Text="Email" TextColor="Red"/>
            <Editor BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=MyPage}" Text="{Binding obj.email}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <Editor BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=MyPage}" Text="Image" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <Image BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=MyPage}" Source="{Binding obj.avatar}"/>



        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

[image: this is what i am getting]

Comment: What just happened to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60409947/issue-with-showing-the-image/60410462#60410462)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with showing the Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60409947/issue-with-showing-the-image)

Comment: i cant understand it quite well. So i uploaded another question with more detail. So kindly help me

Comment: @JamesS no sir it does not as i am new to C sharp and using xamarin first time

Comment: @SajawalZubairi Instead of uploading a new question for essentially the same question, I would edit your pre-existing question with the additional information.

Comment: You can ask for queries in the comment instead of opening a new question. To help you further I need few data. What is the namespace of your Data class??

Comment: @Nikhileshwar namespace is demo

Comment: @JamesS OK sir!

Comment: I have added an answer with more details. could you please check it. If you have any query please ask it here in comments. Please don't create another question just to add more details to your query Use the edit option. Seeing the same question I just now answered was so funny. :>

Comment: @Nikhileshwar Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Suppression State
Error XLS0414 The type 'local:ImageUriConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. demo Secondpage.xaml (I am getting this error with two more errors )

Comment: Where did you add the ImageUriConverter class?

Comment: @Nikhileshwar in the same data class as you said inside of demo namespace

Comment: I have updated the answer. if you are having trouble adding this. Add a new class to the project and replace teh file with the first code snippet in my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208562/discussion-between-nikhileshwar-and-sajawal-zubairi).

Comment: Please do not ask duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

Since the value of `obj.avatar` is of type string and `Source` of `ImageSource` has to be of type `ImageSource`. Use converter for this.

**Converter code**

Add it in the same namespace as your Data class.

```cs
namespace demo
{
    public class ImageUriConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                return ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(value.ToString()));
            }

            return null;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Set a static resource for your converter in page resource

**Data Page Xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:demo"
    x:Class="demo.Data" x:Name="MyPage" >
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <local:ImageUriConverter x:Key="imageConverter"></local:TestConverter>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

**Converter usage with binding**

```
<Image HeightRequest="300" Source="{Binding obj.avatar, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: cant see image 

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another image property for ImageSource like below :

```
private ImageSource img;
    public ImageSource Img
    {
        get { return img; }
        set
        {
            img = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

private UserDTO Obj;
    public UserDTO obj
    {
        get { return Obj; }
        set
        {
            Obj = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Now

```
 public Data(UserResponse result)
    {
        //show = test;
        InitializeComponent();
        obj = result.Data;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.avatar))
        {
            Img = await getImageSource(obj.avatar);
        }

    }
```

and bind Img property to your XAML code like below :

```
<StackLayout Padding="20, 60">
        <Label Text="Id" TextColor="Red" />
        <Editor BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=MyPage}" Text="{Binding obj.id}"   IsReadOnly="True" />
        <Label Text="First Name" TextColor="Red"/>
        <Editor BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=MyPage}" Text="{Binding obj.first_name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <Label Text="Last Name" TextColor="Red"/>
        <Editor BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=MyPage}" Text="{Binding obj.last_name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <Label Text="Email" TextColor="Red"/>
        <Editor BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=MyPage}" Text="{Binding obj.email}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <Editor BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=MyPage}" Text="Image" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <Image BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=MyPage}" Source="{Binding Img}" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"/>



    </StackLayout>
```

Add below method to get image source:

```
public async Task<ImageSource> getImageSource(string url)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = Client.DownloadData(url);
        return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(byteArray));
    }
```

Now  get image in Img

Img = await getImageSource(obj.avatar);

Output :

[image]

Hope it will help you

Thanks

Comment: still cant see the image 

Comment: It is working for me I am sharing you complete XAML code please check again

Comment: the one you shared is same as of mine but still no help

Comment: UserDTO is like your  MyUser model , hope above answer will help you

Comment: doing everything as you said but still cant see any image (i am using an android device)

Comment: For android need to do some extra effort as from url directly image not load

Comment: Now get image in Img

Img = await getImageSource(obj.avatar); where do i put these lines?

Comment: and i am getting this error "name Client does not exist in the current context"

Comment: static WebClient Client = new WebClient();

Add this global variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208569/discussion-between-rajendra-and-sajawal-zubairi).